# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1327 throw err; ^ SyntaxError:

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

im coding a discord bot in discord.js13 with some help from discord.js guide.
everything went good until registration of the slash commands. I think im doing everything good,
but i got "Syntax error" in config.json file (I dont see any error).
terminal shows this:

C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Nowy folder (2)\src>node deploy-commands.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1327
throw err;
^

SyntaxError: C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Nowy folder (2)\src\config.json: Unexpected end of JSON input

anyway, this is my code for deploy-commands.js, config.json, and index.js.

config.json

```
{
    "clientId": "1130870205183184979",
    "guildId": "1120363002705743874",
    "token": "my token is here"
}
```

deploy-commands.js

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');

const commands = [
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('ping').setDescription('bot test'),
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('server').setDescription('Odpowiada z informacją o serwerze!'),
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('user').setDescription('Odpowiada z informacją o użytkowniku!'),
]
    .map(command => command.toJSON());

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: commands })
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
    .catch(console.error);
```

and index.js (i tried to make bot send pictures from my pc)

```
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});



if (message.content === '!random') {
    // get a random index between 0 and length
    const idx = (len) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (len));

    // get all the files in the directory
    const files = fs.readdirSync('/images/');

    // get file from directory
    const myImage = files[idx(files.length)];
    
    // send image to channel
    message.channel.send({ files: [`/images/${myImage}`] });
}

client.login('token')
```

i tried searching for an solution online, checking all files, I even tried asking chatgpt

Comment: seems to be no problem. Is the last line of config.json missing in the editor?